# Knitr with the "--biblatex" option

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, biblatex

I'm writing a document in **R Markdown** with **RStudio**. While the default citations/bibliography options work well, when doing a TeX/PDF export I would prefer to have the intermediate `.tex` source use the `\autocite` and `\autocites` commands instead of having the citations as regular text. This can be achieved with **`pandoc`** by specifying the `--biblatex` argument.

However, when I add the `pandoc_args: ["--biblatex"]` in the YAML front-matter, the citations are not rendered (appear as just the @Author2015 tags, in **bold**) and the bibliography is not appended to the output. I also get an error in the console:

> Error in yaml::yaml.load(front_matter) : Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 23, column 1could not find expected ':' at line 24, column 1

Unfortunately, there is nothing significant at line 23 or 24.

Am I doing something wrong or is such functionality not available? Are there any other methods of "knitting" the R Markdown source to obtain hyperlinked citations in the TeX/PDF output?

*EDIT*: alternatively, is there a way of embedding calls to `biber` in the markdown file so that it's run on the knitted latex source before rendering to PDF? It would be nice to have that done automatically instead of going to the terminal for every export.

---

I'm using **RStudio** version 0.98.1103, **RMarkdown** 0.5.1 and **knitr** 1.9. My front matter is:

```
---
title: Title
author: "Name Surname"
date: "30/03/2015"
output:
    pdf_document:
        fig_caption: yes
        keep_tex: yes
        latex_engine: xelatex
        number_sections: yes
        toc: yes
        toc_depth: 3
        pandoc_args: [
            "--biblatex"
        ]
    html_document:
        fig_caption: yes
        number_sections: yes
        theme: default
        toc: yes
        toc_depth: 3
bibliography: refs.bib
csl: harvard1.csl
---
```

Comment: Your MWE works fine here (R 3.3.1, rmarkdown_0.9.6, Rstudio 0.99.489): I get `\autocite` in the tex file and a formatted bibliography. The `Error in yaml` suggests you may have a syntax error in your actual front matter; the bold **@refkey** happen sometimes when the refkey is not found in the bibfile, so you should also check that.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with the same problem, here's what I have in my YAML header right now:

```
pandoc_args: ["--biblatex","--latex-engine=xelatex"]
csl: csl/chicago-author-date.csl
header-includes:
    - \usepackage[authordate, notes, language=english, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

My best trick right now is to go back to a latex version of what I'm trying to write in .Rmd, then run
`pandoc --biblatex 1f.tex -o 1f.md`.
Then, I can insert this into the .Rmd. It correctly converted `\cite[pg]{citekey}`.